# Choose between two templates render with Marionette

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I use Marionette (Backbone.js) on my Rails app.

What i want to do is load another template if matches an id, this is what i have

**join_room.html.slim** file

```
...
MyAppManager.start({
      tmpltRoute: templateRoute
});
...
```

**menu_view.js.coffee**

```
@MyAppManager.module "Layout", (Layout, MyAppManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  Layout.MenuView = Marionette.ItemView.extend
    initialize: (options)->
      @isPremium = options.isPremium
      @isStandard = options.isStandard
      @tmpltRoute = options.tmpltRoute
    template: JST[this.tmpltRoute]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `getTemplate` on your `ItemView` to achieve this (see docs)

https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.0/marionette.view.html#change-which-template-is-rendered-for-a-view

```
getTemplate: function(){
    if (this.model.get("foo")){
      return JST[foo];
    } else {
      return JST[bar];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Layout.MenuView = Marionette.ItemView.extend 
    template: JST["marionette/app/templates/layout-menu"] 
    getTemplate: -> 
      if this.isCase
        return JST["marionette/app/templates/layout-menu-case"] 
      else 
        return JST["marionette/app/templates/layout-menu"]
```